Formik Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'validateOnChange') using Dynamic Inputs
I'm trying to dynamically add some input fields based on the number on one field setNoOfVessels, I'm trying to use the FieldArray component from Formik to achieve this:
    const validationSchema = Yup.object({        
        setNoOfVessels: Yup.number().min(1, 'At least one vessel is required').required('Required'),
        vessels: Yup.array().of(
            Yup.object({
                vesselName: Yup.string().required('Please enter vessel name'),
            })
        )
    })

    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {            
            setNoOfVessels: 1,
            vessels: [{
                vesselName: '',
            }]
        },
        validationSchema: validationSchema,
        onSubmit: (values, onSubmitProps) => {           
            console.log(values)            
        }
    })

    return (
        <form className='contact-form mt-4' onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
            <div className='col-12 col-md-4'>
                    <TextField
                        fullWidth
                        name='setNoOfVessels'
                        label='Number of Vessels'
                        value={formik.values.setNoOfVessels}
                        type='number'
                        InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: '1' } }}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            const numVessels = parseInt(e.target.value, 10) || 1;
                            const currentVessels = formik.values.vessels.length;
                            if (numVessels > currentVessels) {
                                for (let i = currentVessels; i < numVessels; i++) {
                                    formik.values.vessels.push({ vesselName: '' });
                                }
                            } else {
                                formik.values.vessels.splice(numVessels);
                            }
                            formik.setFieldValue('setNoOfVessels', numVessels);
                        }}
                            error={formik.touched.setNoOfVessels && Boolean(formik.errors.setNoOfVessels)}
                            helperText='Please enter number of vessels'
                            variant='standard'
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className='row'>
                        <FieldArray name='vessels'>
                            {() => (
                                <div className='col-12 col-md-4'>
                                    {formik.values.vessels.map((vessel, i) => (
                                        <div key={i}>
                                            <h4>{`Vessel #${i + 1}`}</h4>
                                            <TextField
                                                fullWidth
                                                name={`vessels[${i}].vesselName`}
                                                label='Vessel Name'
                                                value={formik.values.vessels[i].vesselName}
                                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                                error={formik.touched.vessels && Boolean(formik.errors.vessels[i].vesselName)}
                                                helperText={formik.touched.vessels && formik.errors.vessels[i].vesselName}
                                                variant='standard'
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    ))}
                                </div>
                            )}
                        </FieldArray>
                    </div>
        </form>
    )


Whenever I try to change the value of setNoOfVessels or vessels[i].vessleName I get the error. I've tried changing the initial values and they are reading correctly.
I apparently need to add some filler text here because I'm being told my code to comment ratio is too high. I don't know how much more I can explain the issue.
**Update: If I omit the FieldArray Block I get no issues updating the setNoOfVessels field.

import {FieldArray, FormikProvider, useFormik} from 'formik'
Wrap your form in FormikProvider
<FormikProvider value={formik}>


 {...  your existing code }

</FromikProvider>

